# How can I call TriggerJob with custom jobDataMap?

Tags: quartz.net

I've got a Quartz.NET job which I set up as follows:

```
var jobKey = new JobKey("JobName", "JobGroup");
var triggerKey = new TriggerKey("JobName", "JobGroup");
var jobData = new JobDataMap();
jobData.Add("SomeKey", "OriginalValue");
var jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<JobClass>()
                    .WithIdentity(jobKey)
                    .StoreDurably()
                    .UsingJobData(jobData)
                    .Build();
Scheduler.AddJob(jobDetail, true);
var triggerDetail = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                        .StartNow()
                        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.OnEveryDay()
                            .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(04, 07))
                            .EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(06, 07))
                            .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
                        .ForJob(jobKey)
                        .Build();
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(triggerDetail);
```

I am trying to manually trigger that job using the following code:

```
var jobData = new JobDataMap();
jobData.Add("SomeKey", "SomeValue");
TaskScheduler.Scheduler.TriggerJob(new Quartz.JobKey("JobName", "JobGroup"), jobData);
```

When I run the manual trigger this piece of code, the value in

```
context.JobDetail.JobDataMap["SomeKey"]
```

is

```
"OriginalValue"
```

rather than

```
"SomeValue"
```

as I would expect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both trigger and job have jobData.

Line `TaskScheduler.Scheduler.TriggerJob(new Quartz.JobKey("JobName", "JobGroup"), jobData);`
assigns jobData to trigger. You can see 'SomeValue' in context.Trigger.JobDataMap["SomeKey"]

Answer (score 0):

Using a reference type works:

```
//A simple class used here only for storing a string value:
public class SimpleDTO
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

void Work() {
    var dto = new SimpleDTO();
    dto.Value = "OriginalValue";
    JobDataMap data = new JobDataMap();
    data["Key"] = dto;

    TaskScheduler.Scheduler.TriggerJob(new Quartz.JobKey("JobName", "JobGroup"), jobData);

    //read modified new value:
    var resultDto = (SimpleDTO)data["Key"];
    Assert.AreEqual("NewValue", resultDto.Value);
}

public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    var simpleDTO = (SimpleDTO)context.MergedJobDataMap["SomeKey"];

    //set a new value:

    simpleDTO.Value = "NewValue";
}
```